# How to change timezone in planetscale

Tags: mysql, planetscale

I'm currently using **mysql** base online database service, 'Planet Scale'. But having trouble on changing timezone.

I tried to set timezone by using following query in Planet Scale online console.
`

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+9:00';
SET time_zone = '+9:00';`
```

It returned no error, but didn't work.

So, I tired to find the configuration file to change timezone on other way, but failed since it was cloud database service.

Is there any way to successfully change timezone?